# Read more link with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein

I am trying to create a simple Read More example. It consists of a paragraph and a button with half of the paragraph enclosed in a span tag which is initially set to hidden. When user clicks on Read More button the hidden span shows up. I have got the working code but just want to do a fade in effect like JQuery but with pure Javascript. Anyone please help.

```js
var span = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
var hideshow = document.getElementById('hideshow');

span.style.display = 'none';

hideshow.onclick = function() {
  span.style.display = 'block';
};
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa maiores dolore earum ducimus molestiae, aut. <span>Quisquam consequuntur, maiores et, doloremque atque provident similique consequatur totam voluptas vitae veniam, molestiae laborum.</span></p>

<button id="hideshow">Read More</button>
```

Comment: You will have to create a loop or an interval and gradually increase the opcaity from 0 to 1. There in no ready made function for that in pure js.

Comment: Justy tried this but didn't work. Any idea       span.style.opacity = '0';

hideshow.onclick = Show;
  function Show(){
    for( var i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
  span.style.opacity = '0.1';
    }
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting here

```
span.style.opacity = 0;
```

You'll need to gradually transition the opacity to here.

```
span.style.opacity = 1;
```

You'll need to use an asynchronous construct (`setTimeout`/`setInterval`/`requestAnimationFrame`) for iterating, because a synchronous one (`while`/`for`/`for-in`/`forEach`) will block the main thread, preventing the browser from actually rendering the element with the updated opacity.

```
function fadeIn(element) {

  function transition() {
    if(element.style.opacity < 1) {
      requestAnimationFrame(transition);
      element.style.opacity = Number(element.style.opacity) + 0.05;
    }
  }

  transition();
}
```

Alternatively, if you're happy to use CSS (rather than pure JS) you can do this with classes and transitions.

```
.out {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.in {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

Make sure that the element has the `out` class when it arrives in the DOM, then when you're ready to fade it in, swap it for the `in` class and the browser will handle the animation for you.

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to use a [CSS3 transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) in order to transition the element's opacity.

In the example below, the class `fade-in` is added to the child `span` element when clicking the button.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.read-more');

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var span = event.target.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span');
  span.classList.add('fade-in');
});
```

```css
.show-more span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.show-more span.fade-in {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p class="show-more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa maiores dolore earum ducimus molestiae, aut. <span>Quisquam consequuntur, maiores et, doloremque atque provident similique consequatur totam voluptas vitae veniam, molestiae laborum.</span></p>
<button class="read-more">Read More</button>
```

If you want an approach that works for multiple elements, you could also use the following:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.read-more');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var span = event.target.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span');
    span.classList.add('fade-in');
  });
}
```

```css
.show-more span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.show-more span.fade-in {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p class="show-more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa maiores dolore earum ducimus molestiae, aut. <span>Quisquam consequuntur, maiores et, doloremque atque provident similique consequatur totam voluptas vitae veniam, molestiae laborum.</span></p>
<button class="read-more">Read More</button>

<p class="show-more">Another shorter paragraph. <span>Quisquam consequuntur, maiores et, doloremque atque provident similique consequatur totam voluptas vitae veniam, molestiae laborum.</span></p>
<button class="read-more">Read More</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Josh Crozier

Answer (score 0):

```
var duration = 2000; // msecs

document.getElementById('hideshow').onclick = () => {
   requestAnimationFrame((start_time) => {
      var anim = (time) => {
         var p = (time - start_time) / duration;
         (p < 1) && requestAnimationFrame(anim);
         span.style.opacity = 1 - p;
      }
      anim(start_time);
   })
}
```

Comment: Code dump. Not helpful