# How can we limit a string to a given number of characters in Php

Tags: php, yii2

How can we limit a string to a given number of characters in Php ?

Comment: give example please

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: like , i had a home page where event description is about a page but i only want to show some limited character of event description in homepage and display full description in event details page which is opened when someone need to know full detail of event

Comment: [Read more link using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261680/read-more-link-with-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty. For example only:

```
function contentPreview($inputString, $limit = 200)
{
    $inputString = strip_tags($inputString);
    $inputString = preg_replace('/\s+|&nbsp;/', ' ', $inputString);
    return preg_match('#^(.{' . $limit . ',}?)\s+#su', $inputString, $match)
        ? $match[1] . '...' : $inputString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use default built in StringHelper ? no need to create custom functions

```
StringHelper::truncate($mycontent,100,"...")
```