# How to add a read more/read less button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used the following grid card template from [CodePen](https://codepen.io/littlesnippets/pen/VebNdE)

There is already a `read more` button added in the card, but it doesnt function properly, as when I click the button nothing happens, like there is no code given to it. What I want is when I click the button, I want rest of the text to appear and accoridngly, it should say `read less` button when you click `read more`. How would I make that work? I tried searching it up on google but this example seems too complex to implement the way I know/learned.

Code:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,800);
figure.snip1311 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 315px;
  max-height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #07090c;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-perspective: 50em;
  perspective: 50em;
}
figure.snip1311 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
figure.snip1311 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
figure.snip1311 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
figure.snip1311 h3,
figure.snip1311 p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
figure.snip1311 h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
figure.snip1311 p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
figure.snip1311 .read-more {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}
figure.snip1311 .read-more:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
figure.snip1311:hover img,
figure.snip1311.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
}
figure.snip1311:hover figcaption,
figure.snip1311.hover figcaption {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
/* Demo purposes only */
body {
  background-color: #212121;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/projects.css">
    <section id="project">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/project.css">
      <div class="section-title">
        <h2>My Projects</h2>
        </div>
   <figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample94.jpg" alt="sample94"/>
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Norman Gordon</h3>
    <p>I think nighttime is dark so you can imagine your fears with less distraction.</p><a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample98.jpg" alt="sample98"/>
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Jason Response</h3>
    <p>If we wanted more leisure, we'd invent machines that do things less efficiently.</p><a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample98.jpg" alt="sample98"/>
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Jason Response</h3>
    <p>If we wanted more leisure, we'd invent machines that do things less efficiently.</p><a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
</section>
```

When I click Read More, I want rest of the text to appear but how would I accomplish that task? Please help, I tried various methods such as what W3 schools suggested which was to add JS, and then do #more (display: none)...etc but I cant still get it to work properly

Comment: Also have a look at the details/summary HTML elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read more link with pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261680/read-more-link-with-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Add the content you want to hide under all the read more buttons in the html
Then set them to display : none;

Now read through this snippet to understand

---

```js
// Select all the read more buttons and hidden contents
const readMoreButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".read-more"); const hiddenContents = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden"); 
// Now loop over the read more buttons 
readMoreButtons.forEach( (readMoreButton, index) => { 
// Add onclick event listeners to all of them
readMoreButton.addEventListener("click", () => { 
// Change content of read more button to read less based on the textContent
if(readMoreButton.textContent === "Read More") { readMoreButton.textContent = "Read Less"; } 
else { readMoreButton.textContent = "Read More"; } 
// Toggle class based on index
hiddenContents[index].classList.toggle("hidden"); 
})
})
```

```css
.hidden{
display:none;
}
.read-more{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>Hey it's me content</p> 
<div class="read-more">Read More</div> 
<p class="hidden">More Content I need to be shown please</p> 

<p>Hey it's me content</p> 
<div class="read-more">Read More</div> 
<p class="hidden">More Content I need to be shown please </p>
```

Comment: Could you provide a working example with the code I sent above like take any text and hide it and show it like that?

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work, idk what I am doing wrong

Comment: Sorry you weren't doing anything wrong I used = instead of ===